# May Jews make popsicles or icicles on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, orach-chaim, boneh-soter

According to Halacha, is it permissible for Jews to make popsicles/icicles on Shabbat or no?

Would it be a prohibited form of melacha such as Boneh or something  or not at all? Or is this a machloket amongst poskim?

Comment: https://etzion.org.il/en/halakha/orach-chaim/shabbat/dash-freezing-and-thawing-ice

Comment: I heard that Jews created the popsicle. Or at least that's how they got their name. A guy named Eppstein made them for his kids and called them 'eppcicles.' His kids called them 'popsicles' and the rest is history.

Comment: Sephardim make popsicles if they will be consumed on this same Shabbat (no preparing for another day).